how to aggregate the push and pull client of SRS server into one control pannel
I build four SRS  on different servers, and I can see the push and pull client on itself control panel, so how can I see all the push and pull client on one control panel?

What's "SRS"? I don't think the [tag:srs] tag is the one you intended.

the Simple Realtime Server, please refer to https://ossrs.net/lts/zh-cn/

I've corrected the tag for you, since "srs" is meant for something else ("software requirements specification"). Hopefully, now someone who is an expert on SRS and is watching this tag will be able to answer you.

Thanks @k314159 for correcting the tag. For multiple SRS server management, you can use Prometheus exporter, see https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/exporter
